# NoMethodError .to_i ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

A basic code in ruby that isn't working for me.... The error specifies

NoMethodError (undefined method `to_i' for

```
row = row.split(",").map { |x| x.to_i }
```

EDIT:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_i' for [["123,123,123,"]]:Array):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:21:in `import'
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:20:in `each'
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:20:in `import'
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:17:in `each'
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:17:in `import'


  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (8.2ms)
```

Comment: "undefined method `to_i' for" what? Please post the entire error message.

Comment: Please post the entire backtrace

Comment: I have added more information.

Comment: if `row = "123,123,123,"` it works. Now if `row = [["123, 123, 123"]]`, or some kind of array, I get your error of course ... double check your `row` data type

Comment: you are correct. it is an array. thank you

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto: I guess he did `puts row` and then posted its output here as value of `row`. It will print exactly one string, `"123, 123, 123"` :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev @freedom Yeah, well, only with Ruby 1.8 since Ruby 1.9 `Array#to_s` actually calls `inspect` :)

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto: `puts` doesn't rely on `Array#to_s`. If it is passed an array, it prints each element separately (special handling for arrays).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Oops, didn't see `puts` ... you're right of course !

Comment: Note `.map(&:to_i)` is also valid and cleaner

Answer (score 2):

you're receiving that error because you're calling the method  .to_i on an array, which is wrong since that method is of the String class, source :http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i

So in order to fix this we need to take that string from the array so we can turn it into an integer, remember that you started with an array containing an array, so that's why I'm calling .pop twice:

```
    row = [["123, 123, 123"]]
    string_of_numbers = row.pop.pop
    string_of_numbers.split(",").map {|x| x.to_i }
```

If it feels too odd try to play with it on irb, that's usually how I try to sort these kinds of things out, don't forget to always refer to the official documentation